# date and datestring connection

Tags: date

I'm trying to write a code that visits in another website
The other page uses some sort of logic for the dates, for example:

```
634655520000000000 - 23/2/2012 - Feb 23, 2012
634649472000000000 - 16/2/2012 - Feb 16, 2012
634641696000000000 - 7/2/2012 - Feb 7, 2012
634631328000000000 - 26/1/2012 - Jan 26, 2012
```

http://www.tase.co.il/TASE/Statistics/ShortSale/ShortSaleData/ShortSalesWeekly.htm?action=1&issubmitted=1&dt=634679712000000000&dateLinksID=3
is the mar 22, 2012

can someone figure out a connection between the dates and this var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the time starting from `1.1.1601` in steps of 100 nano seconds.